# Creating data for jqPlot using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

I am using http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php which needs to have data given to it in the following format:

```
//JavaScript
var data = [
  ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14],
  ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
];
```

The data is generated serverside with PHP.  I am manually creating the string as follows:

```
//PHP
$string.='["'.$row['name'].'",'.$row['count'].'],';
```

I would rather just create an array, and use json_encode() or something similar to create the data.  Any suggestions how I would do so?

Comment: How about `json_encode($array);`?

Comment: It didn't work. I think because it would encode it as an object with {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "Heavy Industry",
        12
    ),
    array(
        "Retail",
        9
    )
);
$json = json_encode($array);
var_dump($json); // "[["Heavy Industry",12],["Retail",9]]"
```

Comment: Thanks Arxanas.  Maybe it does work :).  Let me check it out and make sure.

Comment: I get different results:

echo manual created string
["Heavy Industry",44],["Retail",24]

echo print_r($array,1)

Array
(
    [Heavy Industry] => 44
    [Retail] => 24
)

echo var_dump($array)
array(7) { ["Heavy Industry"]=> string(2) "44" ["Retail"]=> string(2) "24" }

Comment: But when I run your exact script, I get correct results.  Let me investigate.  Thanks

Comment: Opps, I was doing $array=array("Heavy Industry"=>12, "Retail"=>9);  Thanks for your help!